# MongoDB aggregation to group products with limit is not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aws-lambda, aggregation-framework

We have about 20,000 records in MongoDB products collection. I am using serverless aws lambda.

On product list page, we want to show only unique productStyleId products and no of color options of that product.

productStyleId. is the key to group the products with different color options.

I have prepare an agreegate query to group the records with "productStyleId" and fetchall of products data. Just after that, I have applied the record limit to fetch only about 50 records.

**Problem Statement:** Below query got crashed with just 4,000 records in the products collection.

**What I want:** I want to use limit within the aggregate query. Can we use it?

*[products are being created randomly, if I am applying limit in query, it won't include all the products with same "productStyleId". It only include first 50 products and group them. Even if there are more products with same productStyleId in the collection]*

```
const data = [
    {
        companyId: "xyz",
        name: "Table 1",
        color:"Red"
        productStyleId: "abc-123"
    },
    {
        companyId: "xyz",
        name: "Chair 1",
        color:"Red"
        productStyleId: "abc-456"
    },
    {
        companyId: "xyz",
        name: "Table 2",
        color:"Blue"
        productStyleId: "abc-123"
    },
    {
        companyId: "xyz",
        name: "Chair 2",
        color:"Green"
        productStyleId: "abc-456"
    },
    {
        companyId: "xyz",
        name: "Chair 3",
        color:"Blue"
        productStyleId: "abc-456"
    },
]

let products = await ProductSchema.aggregate([
     {$match: {companyId:"xyz"}},
     {$group: {_id: "$productStyleId", total: {$sum: 1}, product: {$push: '$$ROOT'}}},
     {$sort: {"product.createdAt":-1}},
]);
    
const offset = 0;
const limit = 50;
let result = products.slice(offset, offset + limit);

// current output. Working for 3,500 records, but got crashed in 4,000 records. 
[
    {
        _id:"abc-123",
        total: "2",
        product:{
            companyId: "xyz",
            name: "Table 1",
            color:"Red"
            productStyleId: "abc-123"
        }
    },
    {
        _id:"abc-456",
        total: "3",
        product:{
            companyId: "xyz",
            name: "Chair 1",
            color:"Red"
            productStyleId: "abc-456"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: I guess you can use `{ $limit : 5 }`. see more here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/

Comment: @PankajTanwar I can not simply use the limit, because it will group the products with only 5 records. If one product was created after 100 records, it won't be included in the list. right?

Comment: oh, did you try `distinct()` in mongoose? and do you have index on `productStyleId`

Comment: @PankajTanwar distinct did not work for me as I want to group it with `productStyleId` and count of products with same `productStyleId`